# res.json converts object into array nodejs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, routes

I'm responding with a JSON in my routing with the following

```
app.get('/loginerr', function(req, res, next){
    var message = req.flash('signupMessage');
    res.json({'error' : message});
});
```

The message is a simple String type but the JSON object is sent inside an array like this:

```
{
  "error": [
  "The email is already taken"
  ]
}
```

As you can see there is a pair of brackets for an array in the response. How I get rid of them?

Comment: `The message is a simple String type`; no; it's an array.  That's what the JSON is telling you.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this :

```
var message = req.flash('signupMessage')[0];
res.json({'error' : message});
```

Comment: Yea, I figured out earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that the req.flash object **is an array**.

I just had to take the only and first element of the array:

```
res.json({'error' : message[0]});
```